# Conditional include directories for native code in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, build

I'm trying to consume this pre-packaged build of libgmp for Android: https://github.com/Rupan/gmp

My project is built using Android Studio. I can "build" the pre-package library without trouble.

However, the package has different `gmp.h` header files depending on the platform (ie. `arm64-v8a/gmp.h`, `armeabi/gmp.h`, ...). My own native code is being built using CMake. I would like to include the appropriate directory using `include_directories` so I can use the appropriate header file.

Is there a variable or conditional that I can use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arm64-v8a`, `armeabi` are values of [CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/variable/CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI.html) variable. So you may use this variable when declare an include directory:

```
include_directories("<...>/${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI}")
```